# Concurrent Map data structure in Java

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, concurrency, atomic

I have the following Data Structure. I am looking for a data structure that behaves like a concurrent hash map with indexes as key. It needs to be thread-safe. I am looking to get better performance than a concurrent hash map with the following data structure, and my experiments show me that I do.

So my question is:
**Am I missing something with this implementation?**  
I know the bitset is not atomic, however the binary semaphore in the add/remove should take care of that.

```
public class NewDS
{
    private BitSet bs = null;
    private AtomicIntegerArray arr = null;
    private int size;
    private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1, true);
    public NewDS( int size) {
            this.bs = new BitSet(size);
            this.arr = new AtomicIntegerArray(size);
    }
    public int put (int hashChunkId) throws InterruptedException {
            semaphore.acquire();
            int index = bs.nextClearBit(0);
            arr.set(index, hashChunkId);
            semaphore.release();
            return index;
    }

    public void remove(int index) throws InterruptedException {
            semaphore.acquire();
            bs.clear(index);
            semaphore.release();
    }
```

}

Comment: The "binary semaphore" is just creating complete synchronization around `put` and `remove` calls, not letting them be concurrent at all.

Comment: Yes, agreed. But this still gives me better performance than ConcurrentHashMap. I am testing with 5 threads (if that matters)

Comment: What is your question, exactly?   "Does this code work?"  or "How does this code work?"  are not on-topic.

Comment: Your data structure doesn't in any way behave like a Map, so if you're *"looking for a data structure that **behaves like a** concurrent hash **map** with indexes as key"*, then what does the performance metrics of your data structure have to do with anything?

Comment: It is a hash map in a way cause I am able to look up  using key/index [look-up function not included in the code].

Comment: How did you measure that?  Show _all_ the details; determining which things provide "better performance" in Java is _super_ hard.

Comment: I have 5 threads, that put 500,000 records into each data structure. I measure the time taken (using System.nanaTime() ) to put 2500000 items and compare the times.